# New Ubuntu User - SSH Using CMD/Terminal Works However VS Code Remote-SSH Permission Denied

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, visual-studio-code

- This is Windows 10 local to Ubuntu Server 18.04 remote.
  **Created a new Ubuntu user.**
- Using password authentication.
- Login to the server with the new user using normal CMD as well as VS Code terminal works.
- VS Code Remote-SSH works with another remote user using key authentication and on another server using password authentication.
- Once it fails subsequent attempts time out repeatedly. I have tried restarting ssh on the remote but it seems the only way to ssh in again is to wait at least up to 5-10 minutes.
- I've set
  "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": true,
  "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false

**Permission denied, please try again.**
**Resolver error: The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe**

```
[19:37:42.871] Log Level: 2
[19:37:42.928] remote-ssh@0.51.0
[19:37:42.929] win32 x64
[19:37:42.938] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+7b22686f73744e616d65223a223139322e3136382e302e313430222c2275736572223a2273736820646576227d", attempt 1
[19:37:42.939] SSH Resolver called for host: ssh <USER@IP>
[19:37:42.939] Setting up SSH remote "<IP>"
[19:37:43.135] Using commit id "ff915844119ce9485abfe8aa9076ec76b5300ddd" and quality "stable" for server
[19:37:43.142] Install and start server if needed
[19:37:43.155] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[19:37:44.247] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
[19:37:44.252] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 35093 "ssh <USER@IP>" bash
[19:37:44.262] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[19:37:45.173] > 
>
> ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[19:37:45.174] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[19:37:45.290] > 
> 
[19:37:45.850] > ssh <USER@IP>'s password: 
[19:37:45.851] Showing password prompt
[19:37:54.970] Got password response
[19:37:54.971] "install" wrote data to terminal: "********"
[19:37:55.008] > 
> 
[19:37:56.507] > Permission denied, please try again.
> 
[19:37:56.526] > ssh <USER@IP>'s password: 
[19:37:56.527] Showing password prompt
[19:38:00.659] Got password response
[19:38:00.659] "install" wrote data to terminal: "********"
[19:38:00.698] > 
> 
[19:38:19.645] > ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to <IP> port 22: Connection timed ou
> t
> 
[19:38:19.681] > The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
> 
[19:38:19.996] "install" terminal command done
[19:38:19.997] Install terminal quit with output: The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
[19:38:19.998] Received install output: The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
[19:38:20.000] Resolver error: The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe
[19:38:20.012] ------
```

I also opened an issue:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/2841

Answer (score 0):

I had the syntax of the Remote-SSH dialog incorrect.
**Incorrect** syntax: `ssh test@host.com`
Correct syntax: `test@host.com`